# What does this kind of declaration of parameters signal (swift)?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I am a beginner programmer and reading a book on iOS programming.

[image]

What does this mean? It takes a parameter of CGSize, then returns a CGFloat, and then a UIImage? What is the point of something like that?

Comment: Here makeRoundedTectangleMake is returning closure(self-contained blocks of functionality) https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Closures.html

Comment: See "Function Types as Return Types" in https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Functions.html.

Answer (score 2):

The following declaration would be more readable when it will look like that:

```
func makeRoundedRectangleMaker(_ sz:CGSize) -> ((CGFloat) -> UIImage?) {
    return nil
}
```

This function takes a `CGSize` as a parameter method and returns a closure which could be also any kind of function with that type.
Here [at this link](http://fuckingswiftblocksyntax.com/) you can read more about it.

Also, you can create a `typealias` for closures, so the function could look like that:

```
typealias CustomNameOfClosure = (CGFloat) -> (UIImage?)

func makeRoundedRectangleMaker(_ sz:CGSize) -> CustomNameOfClouse {
    return nil
}
```

Hope it helps you :)

Comment: Doesn't have to be a closure; it can return any kind of function.

Answer (score 0):

Here your function Return  (CGFloat) -> UIImage.

Means your func makeRoundedRectangleMaker(_ sz:CGSize) return function which has CGFloat datatype argument and returns UIImage datatype value

for ex.

```
 func makeRoundedRectangleMaker(_ sz:CGSize) -> ((CGFloat) -> UIImage?) {
    return sampleFunc(sz)
}

func sampleFunc(_ input: CGSize) -> Int {
    return UIImage
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Look at a piece of code, the realization of this function should be like this

```
func makeRoundedRectangleMaker(_ sz:CGSize) -> (CGFloat) -> UIImage {

    var tempClosure = {(float:CGFloat) -> UIImage in
        UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(sz)
        let context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()
        context?.setFillColor(UIColor(colorLiteralRed: 0, green: 0, blue: 0, alpha: Float(float)).cgColor)
        context?.fill(CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: sz.width, height: sz.height))
        let img = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
        UIGraphicsEndImageContext()
        return img ?? UIImage()
    }

    return tempClosure
}
```

'(_ sz:CGSize)' this is parameter of function ,'(CGFloat) -> UIImage' this is return of function,You can think '(CGFloat) -> UIImage' is A function, also can be thought of as '(CGFloat) -> UIImage' is A closure, closure == function in swift